# The namespace you were looking for could not be found

Tags: git, npm, gitlab

I'm running an app which uses another repo as a dependency I've added this dependency as a ssh, As u can see below in my `package.json`

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "package_name": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com:group-name/repo-name.git --legacy-peer-deps",
}
...
```

But when i run `npm install` it fails with below error message.

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@gitlab.com/group-name/repo-name.git --legacy-peer-deps.git
npm ERR! remote: 
npm ERR! remote: ========================================================================
npm ERR! remote: 
npm ERR! remote: The namespace you were looking for could not be found.
npm ERR! remote: 
npm ERR! remote: ========================================================================
npm ERR! remote: 
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

It seems like authentication issue but I've setup my ssh key with gtilab properly and it's working on cloning repos.

Comment: This is most likely a gitlab configuration error. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/index.html#namespaces for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try the same npm command with:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'
npm install
```

That way, you will see what Git is using when doing its SSH call, and if it does use your SSH key.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the 'git+ssh://git@gitlab.com:group-name/repo-name.git' to https://gitlab.com:group-name/repo-name.git

I had a similar problem and after changing the url, I was able to successfully push.